# How to provide a parameter to a JAX-WS web service handler?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, handler

Ten years ago, I created several applications with Weblogic 8.1 (J2EE 1.4) and JAX-RPC, which contained mainly Web services. Eeach call of these web services was logged in a database thanks to a web service handler which I could define with a XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hc:wlw-handler-config xmlns:hc="http://www.bea.com/2003/03/wlw/handler/config/">
    <hc:handler-chain name="HistHandler">
        <hc:handler handler-name="HistLogger" handler-class="class implementing  the handler">
            <hc:init-param>
                <hc:description>description of the parameter</hc:description>
                <hc:param-name>name of the parameter</hc:param-name>
                <hc:param-value>value of the parameter</hc:param-value>
            </hc:init-param>
        </hc:handler>
    </hc:handler-chain>
</hc:wlw-handler-config>
```

As you can see, it was possible to provide a parameter to the JaxRpc Handler, and I used this feature to provide the name of the application the web service belonged to, so that this application name could be stored in the database with the soap request.

I have to implement the same thing today, but the technology has changed. I have to use now J2EE 1.6 (Tomee++ 1.6.0.1), and JAX-WS has replaced JAX-RPC.
I still can specify a web service handler with a XML file like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
    <handler-chain>
        <handler>
            <handler-name>Name of the handler</handler-name>
            <handler-class>class implementing the handler</handler-class>
        </handler>
    </handler-chain>
</handler-chains>
```

As you can see, it seems that there is not any more the possibility to provide a parameter to the handler.

So my question is : has that feature really disappeared ? Is there realy no way to provide a parameter to the handler class ?

Answer (score 4):

You're correct, the `<init-param>` has been yanked from the configuration options in JAX-WS. [From the JSR-109 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr109/index3.html):

> The element `init-params` in the deployment descriptors is no longer
>   used for JAX-WS based container. If needed, the developer should use
>   the environment entry elements () declared in the
>   application component's deployment descriptor for this purpose. These
>   can be injected into the handler using the `@Resource` annotation or
>   looked up using JNDI.

What this means for you is that you're to define your init params as vanilla JNDI entries and inject them into your handler as `@Resources` viz

- In the web.xml:

  ```
  <env-entry>
      <description>Description</description>
      <env-entry-name>PROPERTY_NAME</env-entry-name>
      <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
      <env-entry-value>property_value</env-entry-value>
  </env-entry>
  ```
- In your handler

  ```
  @Resource String PROPERTY_NAME;
  ```